# A unified database for CNV, SNP, Indel and MSI

Tags: snp, mutations, cnv, indel

I am looking for a database or different databases where I can find information on different gene variants for a gene. As an example if I enter PPARG, I could be able to see SNPs, CNV, InDels and MSI.

In my understanding the information on SNPs can be downloaded from dbSNPs, MSI from ClinVar, CNV & InDels from dbVar. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Is there a database that houses all of this information at under one roof?

Your suggestions are very welcome.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To Answer my own question, one can use variation viewer to get all the information :)

DisGeNet is another resource.